# ServiceProvider boot not working : Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, module

This is my app/Modules/ServiceProvider.php file:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules;
class ServiceProvider extends  \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
public function boot()
{  
    $modules = config("module.modules");
    while (list(,$module) = each($modules)) {
        if(file_exists(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/web.php')) {
            include __DIR__.'/'.$module.'/web.php';
        }
        if(is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views')) {
            $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views', $module);
        }
    }
}
public function register(){}
}
```

It is not loading my views of modules.

web.php is my routes file, As I am working with Laravel 5.2, it comes with Routes directly inside which it has the web.php file.

Originally the code was with routes.php file.

What am I doing wrong?